# Вызов функционального интерфейса с наследником

Tags: java, ооп, наследование, интерфейс, generics

Есть два класса. Один есть наследник второго

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
```

Есть класс, который имеет метод, совпадающий по сигнатуре, с методом функционального интерфейса

```
class Test {
    private void testB(B arg) {  // Consumer<B>
        ......
    };
}
```

И есть метод, который принимает на вход интерфейс и вызывает его метод

```
void testMethod(Consumer<A> arg) {
    arg.accept(null);
}
```

При попытке вызова

```
Test test = new Test();
testMethod(test::testB);
```

получаю ошибку компиляции

```
incompatible types: A cannot be converted to B
```

При использовании такой сигнатуры

```
void testMethod(Consumer<? extends A> arg)
```

ошибка та же

Можно ли как-то подсунуть вызов `testB` в `testMethod` при условии, что `testMethod` ничего не знает о `B`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задача была решена такой сигнатурой

```
<T extends A> void testMethod(Consumer<T> arg)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо написать метод  следующим образом

```
private void testB(A a) {}
```

Ну можно еще так

```
test.testMethod((b) -> test.testB((B) b));
```

Comment: Это понятно. Но сигнатуру метода `testB` я менять не могу

Comment: См. обновление.

Comment: Мой вариант позволяет уйти от каста

Comment: Каст необходим если вы не будете менять сигнатуры методов.